# Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':androidLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

I've been getting this error for two days now and nothing I've tried worked so far.

I have cleaned it, rebuilt it, invalidated cache, updated Android Studio and its build tools, but absolutely nothing works. My JAVA_HOME is fine, the SDK is fine. I checked everything, but it just doesn't seem to work.

androidLib is one library I'm using and it goes like this

androidLib contains pretty much all my dependencies
template common is a module I created which has androidLib as a dependency (it is being included in the settings.gradle and its respective builds)
template is my project which has template common as a dependency, therefore it has androidLib as well

But it keeps giving me that error and simply none of the androidLib dependencies are being accessed at all, including app compact and things as such.

This is androidLib gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'



dependencies {
      compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.7.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
       compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
       compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.0'
       compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.0'
       compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.0'
       compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
       compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
       compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
       compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-    template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
       compile 'com.vividsolutions:jts:1.13'
       compile 'com.noveogroup.android:android-logger:1.3.5'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
   }

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```

}

This is the template common gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'net.xpece.material:navigation-drawer:0.7.6@aar'
    compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.13'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.1.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.helpshift:android-aar:4.2.0-support'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.0.8'
    compile project(':androidLib')
   }
```

And this it the project gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.altranais.template"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':templatecommon')
}
```

Gradle console

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :androidLib:generateDebugSources, :androidLib:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :androidLib:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :androidLib:mockableAndroidJar, :androidLib:compileDebugSources, :androidLib:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :androidLib:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :templatecommon:generateDebugSources, :templatecommon:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :templatecommon:mockableAndroidJar, :templatecommon:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :templatecommon:compileDebugSources, :templatecommon:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :templatecommon:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:clean
:androidLib:clean
:app:clean UP-TO-DATE
:templatecommon:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:androidLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:androidLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:androidLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:androidLib:compileLint
:androidLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:androidLib:checkReleaseManifest
:androidLib:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:androidLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:androidLib:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:androidLib:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:androidLib:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library
:androidLib:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library
:androidLib:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72330Library
:androidLib:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2330Library
:androidLib:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library
:androidLib:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library
:androidLib:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72330Library
:androidLib:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library
:androidLib:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet840Library
:androidLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable840Library
:androidLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:androidLib:compileReleaseAidl
:androidLib:compileReleaseRenderscript
:androidLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:androidLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:androidLib:mergeReleaseAssets
:androidLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:androidLib:generateReleaseResources
:androidLib:mergeReleaseResources
:androidLib:processReleaseManifest
:androidLib:processReleaseResources
:androidLib:generateReleaseSources
:androidLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
public class AISActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
                                 ^
  symbol: class ActionBarActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    protected DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
              ^
  symbol:   class DrawerLayout
  location: class AISActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
    protected ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
              ^
  symbol:   class ActionBarDrawerToggle
  location: class AISActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class AISActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ais);
                               ^
  symbol:   variable activity_ais
  location: class layout
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:40: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable content_frame
  location: class id
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                        ^
  symbol:   class DrawerLayout
  location: class AISActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable drawer_layout
  location: class id
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
        drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable left_drawer
  location: class id
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
        titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
                 ^
  symbol:   method getResources()
  location: class AISActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
        images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);
                 ^
  symbol:   method getResources()
  location: class AISActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
        activities = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.activities);
                     ^
  symbol:   method getResources()
  location: class AISActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
        textCurrentUser = (TextView)drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable user_name
  location: class id
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
        imageFotoView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fotoView);
                                                     ^
  symbol:   variable fotoView
  location: class id
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.loading,R.string.loading){
                                    ^
  symbol:   class ActionBarDrawerToggle
  location: class AISActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
        super.onDestroy();
        ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class AISActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:85: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:95: error: no suitable method found for makeText(AISActivity,String,int)
                Toast.makeText(AISActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     ^
    method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
      (actual argument AISActivity cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
    method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
      (actual argument AISActivity cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            ^
  symbol: method runOnUiThread(<anonymous Runnable>)
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:102: error: cannot find symbol
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), obj == null ? "NULL" : obj.toString());
              ^
  symbol:   method getClass()
  location: class AISActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), obj == null ? "NULL" : obj.toString(), tr);
              ^
  symbol:   method getClass()
  location: class AISActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:110: error: cannot find symbol
        View view = findViewById(id);
                    ^
  symbol:   method findViewById(int)
  location: class AISActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:131: error: cannot find symbol
        this.showProgressDialog(getString(R.string.loading));
                                ^
  symbol:   method getString(int)
  location: class AISActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:136: error: no suitable constructor found for ProgressDialog(AISActivity)
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                             ^
    constructor ProgressDialog.ProgressDialog(Context,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor ProgressDialog.ProgressDialog(Context) is not applicable
      (actual argument AISActivity cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:151: error: no suitable constructor found for Builder(AISActivity)
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                                          ^
    constructor Builder.Builder(Context,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Builder.Builder(Context) is not applicable
      (actual argument AISActivity cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:165: error: cannot find symbol
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class AISActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:163: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:171: error: cannot find symbol
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class AISActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISActivity.java:169: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISNavigationActivity.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        navigationDrawerAdapter = new AISNavigationDrawerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), titles, images);
                                                                 ^
  symbol:   method getApplicationContext()
  location: class AISNavigationActivity
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISNavigationActivity.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_container));
                                                                     ^
  symbol:   variable left_container
  location: class id
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/activity/AISNavigationActivity.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
            onActivityInteractionListener.openActivityInteraction(getApplicationContext(),position);
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   method getApplicationContext()
  location: class AISNavigationActivity.DrawerItemClickListener
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/adapters/AISNavigationDrawerAdapter.java:52: error: package R does not exist
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
                                 ^
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/adapters/AISNavigationDrawerAdapter.java:53: error: package R does not exist
        TextView txt=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                                                  ^
/Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/adapters/AISNavigationDrawerAdapter.java:57: error: package R does not exist
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon_list);
                                                            ^
Note: /Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/adapters/AISNavigationDrawerAdapter.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/Leonardo/Documents/Android/androidLib/src/main/java/br/com/altranais/lib/socket/SocketClient.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
36 errors

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':androidLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 23.847 secs
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add the error message from Gradle output.

Comment: Pretty much all the errors in there are because the lib is not being accessed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the gradle, I had recently updated to Android Studio 2.0 and it messed up everything. Had to go back to older Android Studio to fix it and be able to use it on 2.0

Comment: what was the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. Manually deleting the build directory fixed it for me.